# Drop privileges in Pass (unix password store tool)

Tags: unix, password-management, privileges

Pass is a Unix command line password manager http://www.passwordstore.org/

To read any stored password one has to input the master-password, it then allows to read/write any password. However this permission is not dropped, even in new terminals one can read or write the passwords.

I want to configure this behavior so that I can manually drop the privileges and/or have them automatically dropped after some time that I choose.